# Sencha Touch sass corrupts png encodings

Tags: sencha-touch, sass, compass-sass

I have been trying to compile the application.sass in my Sencha Touch project into application.css.

According to sencha touch's forum, to compile the sass, I only needed to install compass & chunky_png. That is exactly what I've done. The following are my gems

compass (0.11.beta.7)
chunky_png (1.1.2, 1.1.0)

When I compile the sass. The resulting css seems to contain the included resource from the sass. However, all the png are translated into weird characters. I realize that it is trying to encode the image into base 64, but as far as I know, base 64 strings basically consists of A-Z a-z 0-9 + /, all being readable characters.

Using this generated application.css, my sencha touch app cannot read any of the encoded pngs at all. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue a few weeks ago, but dumping the gems and grabbing the specific versions cleared things up.

Is [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?127994) the thread you've already taken a look at? If so, have you already tried:

```
gem install chunky_png -v 0.12.0
gem install compass—pre
```

That did the trick for me.